# How to store and continously calculate the rolling average of data points

Tags: python, database, nosql

I'm about to develop a quota tracking tool, that needs to account the number of events each user has triggered the last 60 minutes.

I'm free to choose storage method (rdbms, nosql, memory, whatever), and pretty much anything else, but it should accessible to multiple nodes over the network.

I've seen several examples of how to calculate average based on file inputs etc., and I do believe I could sort that part --  but having to also decide a good way of storing the data makes my knees bend.

So far I've considered redis and memcached, but I'm still puzzled about how I should store and access the average data.

It doesn't matter for me where the average calculation is done, whether it's done in the backend or in the code.

Example python code that shows aproximately what I want to achieve:

```
def registerUserEvent(username):
  updateUserEvents(username, getUserEvents() + 1)

def getUserEvents(username):
  return fetchDataFromSomeBackend(username)

def getUserEventsPerHour(username):
  userEvents = getUserEvents(username)
  hourlyAverage = doSomeCalculations(userEvents) # how do I do this?
  return hourlyAverage

def updateUserEvents(username):
  updateBackendSomehow(username, getUserEvents() + 1)
```

Comment: How you do it depends on what technology you use for storage, which depends on the needs of your app.

Comment: Phew, that's a broad one. My first hint would be: make a class and implement the database wrappers, after that, you can play around with `@property` to trigger data alterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend storing events with a timestamp. A record would look like `<timestamp,username,eventid>`.
You can then compute the hourly average in the following way:

```
(number of events with username=some_username)/(max_timestamp-min_timestamp).hour()
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't really care much about the eventid, I guess that makes it easier as I just have to store the username and timestamp.

Comment: This is what got me in the right direction. Accepting as answer